# Issue with ciruitikZ package

Tags: errors, circuitikz

I'm trying to use the option `RPvoltages` for the package `circuitikZ version 0.8.3` but I get the following error message:
`` ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `RPvoltages' for package `circuitikz'. ``

This option however, is mentioned in the package manual [(link)](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf)

If I omit this option, the package produces the figure shown below.

[image]

**Code used**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to[battery1,v=1<\volt>] (0,2) to [short](2,2) to [C=1<\farad>](2,0) to [short](0,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is your TeX distribution up-to-date?

Comment: Thank you @JouleV, I just checked, MiKTex is up to date. I'm using Texmaker as my editor on a Windows machine

Comment: I can find no mention of RPvoltages in either the manual or the source.  I did fine americanvoltages, europeanvoltages, straightvoltages and oldvoltagedirection.

Comment: official version of package on `ctan` doesn't have this option. you give the link to documentation to probably the future version which is still not available on `ctan`. if you like to use it, than you need to download package from page where you find its manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual given in question is for an unreleased (git) version of `circuitikz`. The option `RPvoltage` is not supported in version 0.8.3.

Use the git version if you want to use this option.

Comment: It might be already released, but not included in your Tex installation by your package manager. Luckily, you can just download the latest version by hand from here: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/
and replace the usepackage statement with:
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}